# facebook javascript v2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook javascript v2.0 informs app specific user id. 
But what will happen if any old user uninstall an application and again re install that application after changing the application version?

Will they have new *userid*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He will get the same ID, so you can still identify returning users. I just tested it with an App to be sure: Authorize user, call /me, remove App, authorize user again, call /me > same ID.

Edit: We just discussed this in another thread: [Facebook API 2.1 - About Invite Friends And App-scoped User IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294693/facebook-api-2-1-about-invite-friends-and-app-scoped-user-ids/26294990?noredirect=1#comment41259885_26294990)

It seems that the Scoped ID may change if the user deauthorized your App and authorizes it after a long time. But you would have to delete the user data anyway if the user does not use the App for a long time - data privacy and stuff.