# Facebook API 2.1 - About Invite Friends And App-scoped User IDs

Tags: android, ios, facebook

> Facebook will begin to issue app-scoped user IDs when people first log
>   into an instance of your app coded against v2.0 of the API. With
>   app-scoped IDs, the ID for the same user will be different between
>   apps.

When Invite a Friend, a request send like:{to[0]=10202585439492947, request=345936808908087}, i could get the recipient's id:10202585439492947, is it the recipient's App-scoped User ID?

The user's  App-scoped User ID will always the same? If the user remove my app,then after several days, log into my app again, will the App-scoped User ID same as before?

I Want **Rewarding** the **Sender** and the **Recipient**,But if the App-scoped User ID changed between Sender send the invite and Recipient log into my app, I could locate who invite the new user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve just answered this in another thread: [facebook javascript v2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294032/facebook-javascript-v2-0)

It is an App Scoped ID, and it should stay the same even if the user deauthorizes and authorizes your App again. It will always be same in one App, but it will be different in another App. If you want to match IDs between different Apps, you can use the Business Mapping API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Btw, you are only allowed to reward the Sender if the Recepient accepted the invite, nothing else. See the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ - 4.5 > click on the small question mark icon.

Careful though, if you are using "invitable_friends" you don´t get an App Scoped ID, but an "invite token": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/invitable_friends

Edit: The Scoped ID may change if the user deauthorizes the App and authorizes it again after a long time, but you would need to delete his data anyway for privacy reasons.

Comment: Send Invite Request: get App-scoped User ID: 10202585439492947,Then the Recipient install my app,will the user's App-scoped User ID:10202585439492947?

Comment: @luschn Try reauthenticating after 24 hours.  I seem to recall having a problem with an app-scoped ID changing over time if you uninstalled and reauthenticated at a later time (but that was close to launch and possibly a bug).

AlanGame No, it will not be the same.  The user has not authenticated your app.

Comment: It should not matter after 24 hours imho, because the recipient either accepted the invite in that time or he refused. And if a user removed your App and did not use it for a longer time, he may indeed get a new Scoped ID - you would have needed to delete his data anyway though. data privacy and stuff...

Comment: That's what I was thinking, data is supposed to be removed (technically) after a while and it may be done purposely.

Comment: yeah, and there is that deauth-callback input field in the app settings. although, i doubt that developers really use it. after all it is additional work.

Comment: How to Reward the Sender the the Recipient ? No Way?

Comment: what do you mean? i don´t understand "the the recipient"? you are only allowed to reward the sender, and only after the recipient accepted the invite. see my answer for more information.

Comment: Sorry，mistake,How to Reward the Sender and the Recipient ? No Way?

Comment: "  you are only allowed to reward the sender, and only after the recipient accepted the invite ",But How Could I Know the Recipient accepted the invite? The App Scoped ID Will Change perhaps after  24 hours.

Comment: as i said, it should be no problem because after 24 hours the recipient will either already have accepted the invite or refused it.

Answer (score 0):

If the user logs into your app like normal, it will remain the same.  If the user uninstalls the application and then reauthenticates it at a later date, I believe the ID will be different from previous entries (or so I understand).

Comment: I could get my friend's App-scoped User ID  WhenI invite him (Now He Do Not Install my app), the App-scoped User ID will change 'at a later date'? but how long?Several days ago, an user uninstalls my app, then reinstall and reauthenticates my app,his App-scoped User ID Did changed. But today,i uninstalls,reinstall,reauthenticates, my App-scoped User ID remains the same as before.

Comment: It won't change if he authenticates your app, otherwise it will continue to change every so often.